# how to get the last executed method in code that doesn't terminate?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm modifying a rather big codebase and I'm in the process of debugging. My code doesn't terminate, so I don't get a stacktrace. I tried to isolate the trouble code with breakpoints, but unfortunately it runs through sections that are executed all the time (transaction manager), so I'm clicking to death. Furtermore, i get the impression that the code breaks only under certain conditions, but runs fine most of the time.

Is there a way in Intellij to see the last method that was / the current method that is executed?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace/), a tracing tool, to print out the name of every method entered in your program. There is a sample script that comes with BTrace, called [`AllMethods`](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace/sources/hg/content/samples/AllMethods.java), which does just that.

All of you have to do is start your java process and then run the BTrace script against the JVM's PID. It will print out every method entered. You can restrict it to certain packages if you like. For more information about using BTrace check out this [tutorial](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/07/tracing-java-applications-with-btrace.html).

Comment: with JVM'S PID you mean the process number, i.e. what you get using ps / top?

Comment: @ib84 yes, the process id you see in `ps`

Answer (score 1):

Use a profiler. It will give you a breakdown of which methods are executing, how much time your program spends in each method etc etc. It should be quite easy to find out from there where your program is spending its time.

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html?gclid=CK7TveDrraoCFYVLpgodrzBrVQ) is an example. I think it has a trial / demo version which is fully functional.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the tracing seems to be the specialized solution